# How to extend Ruby Enumerable class max_by to ignore nil?

Tags: ruby, extension-methods, overloading, ruby-1.9.3, enumerator

```
a = [4, 3, 2, nil]
a.max_by { |v| v * 2 } => NoMethodError: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

How to overload max_by to ignore nil values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Ruby: there are so many ways to solve the problem!

A very simple solution is:

```
a.max_by { |v| v.to_f * 2 }
```

since nil coerces to float as 0. This doesn't handle negative values, but since nil is only a single instance of a class called NilClass, now as with all classes in Ruby we can open it an let it learn a littly maths:

```
class NilClass
  # overloading * operator
  def *(y)
    # returning negative infinity: Ruby 1.8.7
    -1.0/0.0
    # returning negative infinity: Ruby 1.9.2
    # -Float::INFINITY
  end
end
```

now we have

```
a.max_by { |v| v * 2 }
```

returning 4.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`Array.compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact) to remove nils before you call `max_by`.

```
a.compact.max_by { |v| v * 2 }
```

Comment: Although it works, it doesn't quite answer the OP question (How to extend Enumerable class).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one:

```
a.max_by { |v| v.nil? ? -Float::INFINITY : v }
#=> 4
```

For your example this is obviously more complicated than `compact`, but if you want to sort the array and keep the `nil` values it's a handy trick. Or if you want to sort in a strange way, like zeroes to the end:

```
[0,4,5,6,1,9].sort_by { |v| v.zero? ? Float::INFINITY : v }
#=> [1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 0]
```